# Sharepoint: Where to store assets used in my custom master page?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I'm creating a custom master page for my SharePoint 2010 publishing site. There are images, css files and js files associated with this custom master page. Where should they be stored?

I'm using the SiteAssets library for now - is this a good choice?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah that is a good choice, also make sure you [Provision](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms441170.aspx) all these files using Feature, this way upate of Files becomes easier.

Answer (score 3):

In my opinion, you should store everything under the site collection libraries, this way you get:

1. Easy recovery in the cases you need to re-install the server[s]
2. Versioning and permissions on resources
3. Separation of resources between site collection
4. Simple deployment between environments, as you do not need to copy the files manually or design and deploy a feature to do it for you

The preferred place is of course Style Library, this is what it is intended for.

Comment: Thanks. So what is the SiteAssets library for then?

Comment: Your videos and stuff like that, content, not look&feel

Answer (score 2):

If you are creating and deploying your files through code, you can also use the _layouts directory to store your files.  This makes it simpler to share files between site collections.  Visual Studio 2010 makes it really simple to add a reference to the Images folder and any files will then be deployed to the _layouts/Images URL.

The only advantage of this is that a site collection administrator cannot make changes to these files, only someone with access to the physical server.  (Although this can also be a disadvantage if your logos or images are changing regularly).

Answer (score 0):

I usually store them in _catalogs/masterpage/ORGNAME/...

You can refer this blog for actual implementation
http://markviky.blogspot.com/2010/11/sharepoint-2010-web-content-management.html

-Vighnesh Bendre